# SQL (Redshift) how to fill the sparse value with the previous non-empty column value for the same row

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, fill

How could I fill the value of an empty column (0 is the value) with the previous non-empty column value using SQL (Redshift) ?

**Example:** `tbl` is the name of it with 25 columns, 'index' and up to 24 periods. (Omit the ones in between)

| Index | period_1 | period_2 | period_3 | period_24 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 19.8 | 20.1 | 0 | 17.0 |
| 2 | 15.1 | 0 | 0 | 10.3 |

**Desired Output:**

| Index | period_1 | period_2 | period_3 | period_24 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 19.8 | 20.1 | 20.1 | 17.0 |
| 2 | 15.1 | 15.1 | 15.1 | 10.3 |

How can we do that for each index(row)?

Answer (score 3):

You can use `coalesce()` and `nullif()`:

```
select index, period_1,
       coalesce(nullif(period_2, 0), period_1),
       coalesce(nullif(period_3, 0, nullif(period_2, 0), period_1),
       coalesce(nullif(period_4, 0), nullif(period_3, 0, nullif(period_2, 0), period_1),
       . . . 
from t;
```